# Shortcut loading on a Taskbar Folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, shortcuts, toolbar

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this into a proper question for the Title. However I've got a folder on my C:\ called Games that I have all the shortcuts for all of my games and some programs thrown into. I then loaded that folder onto my task bar under the Toolbars. So that when I click the little ">>" it'll load up all my shortcuts for all my games and programs. Which is about 120 shortcuts. The problem I'm having is that on the first load of this folder it takes a while to load everything and ends up usually freezing up Explorer while it loads. Then it will close and when reopened it will load all the shortcuts that fits on screen, but if I try to scroll down further into the list again it seems to take a while to load all the shortcuts. Its not until I've gone through and seen each one will the list fluidly scroll without issue.

Now my question is, is there a way to pre-load these when my computer starts? Or a different way of saving shortcuts to games so that I can quickly go through them. I've always hated keeping a ton of shortcuts on the desktop, I'd prefer this nice clean look.

The Shortcut folder is on an SSD, and I feel that it tries to verify the install location of each shortcut across 3 other hard drives which is causing it to load slowly. Can you stop that from happening? It loads especially slow if there is a dead shortcut in there of a program or game I uninstalled. In which I get rid of, however it significantly slows the opening down.

[image: Here is what I'm looking at.]